# Need JNI or something simpler?

Tags: java, c, java-native-interface, multilingual

So I have a Java program that captures raw ethernet data in a buffer, and a C program (actually a series of C programs) that decode that data into a usable format and stick it in a file to be analyzed later. I would like to run the Java, have the data sent to the C, a file appended and control return to the original program to listen for more data.

My question is do I really need to use JNI to call this C program since I will be sending data to it, or could I just use JConfic or exec? My files aren't .exec files, so I don't really see the latter working, but I would like to keep this as simple as possible. What do you all think?

Comment: I think you must use JNI ... if you want to send data from Java code to C code

Comment: Even if I sent in as command line arguments?

Comment: You have a Java program capturing Ethernet data? How?

Comment: Datagram sockets, sent over a network via ethernets.

Comment: This is UDP data, not *raw ethernet data*. (But this does not really relate to the question, I just was interested.)

Comment: I suppose you are right, my terminology is rarely as accurate as I would like it to be.

Comment: To begin with, why do you need to use java for you case? Sounds like pretty low-level system programming. In case you need Java to write app to analyse/visualize your data from file, you don't need JNI, you just have regular java program and run it from command line, passing file name as an argument. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the following options:

- You can either create a CLI interface for your C code, then compile that for all supported platforms and execute it from Java
- You can use [JNA](http://jna.java.net/) or [JNI](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/jni/) to create a bridge for calling the library code from Java, but you will still need to compile the C code for all supported platforms, just you would need to supply it as a library now

The easiest way by far is to create a CLI executable that you can call from Java and parse its output. As an added bonus, you'll also be able to use the CLI executable from any other language.

The less easy way is to use JNA. JNA is pretty straight forward to use, but it's not supported everywhere and on every device. For example, Android does not support JNA. Check the specs for your supported devices to find out if you can use JNA with them. Also check out [this tutorial](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jna/) for an very basic introduction to JNA.

The hard way is to use JNI. JNI is not at all straight forward to use. You will need to write lots of glue code to process JVM calls, then some other glue code to compose JVM friendly output. This is however the most widely supported method (works on Android as well). Again, do check the specs for your supported devices to find out if you can use JNI with them. If you want to take the JNI route, you can check out [this tutorial](http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jni/) for a basic introduction.

So, if you don't have very complex things to do (not many functions to support, not many data types), go with JNI. Otherwise, try a more high-level approach.

Comment: I doubt the CLI will work for this application, but thanks for suggesting it. I had never heard of it and it looks interesting, I will no doubt use it for other projects in the future. I think I will go with JNA, it seems to be the best option for this. I certainly don't need Android support in this case, and would prefer to not fiddle with JNI for what shouldn't be excessively complicated.

Comment: By CLI I just mean that instead, or in addition to having a library, also create a command line utility that you can use with Java or with scripting languages. It would just take input from stdin and would output to stdout.

Comment: Sure, even better. You can create an executable in C (aka CLI - command line interface) that can take two parameters - a path to the input file and a path to the output file. When you call the executable from Java, it will process the contents of the input file and will write the results to the output file. Then you can simply read the output file from Java.

Answer (score 1):

Check [JNA](http://jna.java.net/), it is much simpler that JNI.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can run your C programs from Java as separate processes.

Use [java.lang.ProcessBuilder](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) to make a [java.lang.Process](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html), and interact with the input, output and error streams of the Process. Note that the Process will hang if you don't read its output stream.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a pretty straightforward example of using JNA (mentioned by @lexicore ) to call a C function from Java
http://stuf.ro/calling-c-code-from-java-using-jna/

If your Java and C program could be reorganized so that the C program called the Java program then the following article provides an excellent example with code available for download. It basically abstracts out the complexity of using JNI by using a Java Proxy class and a C facade that makes calls to the needed Java functionality.

http://java.sys-con.com/node/45840

Comment: The whole point is that it is a Java run operation, for multi-platform use, however with the complications of extra C headers, I am wondering if that ideal is becoming unrealistic.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, you can communicate from Java with your C program using the C programs process' input and output streams.

It would depend on your problem whether this is actually easier to write than using JNI (or JNA).

Comment: Could you elaborate on when JNI would be better versus JNA?

Comment: I'm not proficient with either one, but here what I gathered: With JNI, you have to directly write your C (or other native language) functions to be called from Java. This means the C functions have to know about JNI. With JNA, you use a Java API to select any existing native functions (which do not have to know about Java).

Comment: I've used both. JNI is faster, JNA is easier. Neither is necessary if you want to launch existing command-line programs.

Answer (score 0):

you can use JNA for your purpose as you have to call C code only,but in future if you have to include calls for C++,JNA will not work,so better you use JNI which will be useful in both the cases,and performance wise also JNI has got significant advantages.